# "Участник на протяжении 1 лет" - в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На днях получил знак "Годовалый", зашел к себе в профиль, а там такая картинка:

> [image: 1 лет]

Конечно, глаза сильно не режет, но все же. Ведь все остальные числительные вроде склоняются правильно, а стаж - нет. На en.SO кстати этой проблемы нет ("1 year" как и должно быть).

Comment: Нашёл в Transifex: «участник на протяжении» [Tx: 5039](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267034), [Tx: 5085](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267089) и [Tx: 6960](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/53412309), «X лет»: судя по всему, [Tx: 1533](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263232). Там неправильная форма (1 лет). Я бы исправил на «1 года» но вопрос в контексте: не нужно ли где-то ещё форма «1 год»?

Comment: Поскольку тут важен точный падеж, я бы не собирал эту фразу из «участник на протяжении» + «один год», а положил бы фразу целиком, чтобы не нужно было угадывать. Так что судя по всему стоит открыть баг локализаторам?

Comment: @VladD, в каком контексте может использоваться "1 лет"? Или имеется в виду, что надо две разные формы "год" и "года"?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага. Я боюсь править «1 лет» на «1 года» потому, что этот же текст может быть используется там, где по контексту нужно «1 год».

Comment: Извиняюсь, что вмешиваюсь. Но зачем здесь вообще нужен родительный падеж? Имхо это усложнение. Можно же как-то и без него обойтись. "Стаж участника 1 год" как вариант.

Comment: @hindmost, но "Стаж участника 1 лет" - это тоже неправильно. Получается, править именно слово "лет" надо в любом случае.

Comment: @VladD Рискнул поправить. Посмотрим, что будет. За одно и для _few_ поправил (было «года»).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На текущий момент проблема не проявляется:

> [image: 1 года]