# Несогласованная форма множественного числа в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Дефект локализации в отображении в профиле.

Воспроизводится так: ищем любого пользователя, который на сайте ровно 2 дня, заходим в профиль, видим:

[image: баг]

Например, сегодня это можно увидеть в [этом профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211886?tab=profile).

Нужные строки в transifex [есть](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267089?qt=%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)*, но но организованы неправильно: количество дней не является частью шаблона (строки содержат лишь «участник на протяжении»), поэтому форма «дня/дней» получается несогласованной.

Судя по всему, требует исправления в движке.

---

*Ссылка откроется только если у вас есть экаунт в transifex.

Comment: Галочку поставь.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А где ответ с текстом «исправлено»? :)

Comment: А что, все 3 имеющиеся не подходят?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я как раз добавил ответ и поставил галочку.

Comment: Ну я посчитал неправильно. Тут других 2 есть - они не подходят?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, они не говорят о решении проблемы, а наоборот добавляют деталей, разве нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема из вопроса исправлена.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю: и не только для таких участников... Вот еще пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильная форма - 3 лет (*трех лет*).

На всякий случай добавлю сюда таблицу согласования для существительных и числительного в родительном падеже:

- 1 (одного) дня, месяца, года
- 2 (двух) дней, месяцев, лет
- 3 (трех) дней, месяцев, лет
- ...
- 10 (десяти) дней, месяцев, лет
- 11 (одиннадцати) дней, месяцев, лет
- ...
- 20 (двадцати) дней, месяцев, лет
- 21 (двадцати одного) для, месяца, года
- ...

Общее правило:

```
n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ? единственноеЧисло : множественноеЧисло
```

Также желательно вместо запятой использовать союз "и", хотя и не обязательно (*"участник на протяжении 3 лет и 7 месяцев"*)

---

Также отмечу, что в именительном или винительном падежах числительного согласование идет по-другому. Т.е. фразы вида "возраст - 2 дня" и "возраст - 2 года, 7 месяцев" являются корректными. Таким образом, исправить проблему можно не путем изменения движка, а путем изменения той части строки, которая есть в transifex.

Comment: С transifex проблем нет, там можно указывать три строки: one/some/many («день/дня/дней»). Но вот с контекстом там проблема: строка собирается из частей («участник на протяжении» + сколько), и во второй части используется именительный падеж вместо родительного. Поэтому стоит не собирать строку из кусочков (это почти никогда не работает), а переводить фразу целиком.

Comment: @VladD ну тогда надо просто указать вместо согласования для именительного падежа («день/дня/дней») согласование для родительного ("дня/дней/дней")

Comment: Мне кажется, это не сработает, т. к. в других языках может в данной точке потребоваться другой падеж.

Comment: @VladD какие "другие языки"? Наверное, вы хотели сказать "другие места"? Если кусок общий с другими - то, разумеется, менять его нельзя.

Comment: Ну да, кусок общий, для всех языков.

Comment: @VladD брр, каких *языков*-то?! Мы же, кажется, только "русскую" часть менять собрались...

Comment: Ну, смотрите. На сайте нету переводов всего сайта на каждый конкретный язык, а только переводы отдельных подстрок. Есть шаблон: `message = "$ID_MEMBER_FOR $ID_DATE(days, months, years)"`, в которую подставляются строки текущего языка. Если вы замените `$ID_DATE` на `$ID_DATE_GENITIVE`, то это сломает языки, в которых в этой точке не родительный падеж. Если вы в _переводе_ `$ID_DATE` используете родительный падеж, это сломает в русском переводе все места, где нужен таки именительный.

Comment: @VladD ну я так и говорил - один фрагмент ($ID_DATE) используется в нескольких местах.

Comment: Окей, тут мы вроде разобрались. Тогда в вашем предложении непонятно, перевод какой из строк следует менять. Перевод строки `$ID_DATE` менять нельзя, как мы уже выяснили. Вы имеете в виду перевод строки `$ID_MEMBER_FOR`? Составление сообщения из `$ID_MEMBER_FOR` и `$ID_DATE` — часть движка, а не перевода, так что это изменить «локально» (то есть, редактированием в transifex) не выйдет.

Comment: @VladD в идеале - что-то делать с движком. Как костыль - изменить $ID_MEMBER_FOR так, чтобы он требовал именительного падежа числительного.

Comment: Хм, у вас есть идеи для перевода? В любом случае, конкатенация локализованных строк **практически всегда** плохо, и катит только как очень временный, ненужный костыль. На немецком, например, текст должен _окружать_ дату: »Der Teilnehmer ist seit $ID_DATE auf der Seite.«

Answer (score 2):

Подобный вопрос уже поднимался: ["Участник на протяжении 1 лет" - в профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-1-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5), и там было хорошее [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2817/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-1-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5#comment8792_2817): вместо

> Участник на протяжении $родительный_падеж

использовать

> Стаж участника $именительный_падеж

(кажется, перед $ просится ещё знак препинания - тире или двоеточие).

---

Вообще, если посмотреть, сейчас какая-то неразбериха в падежах:

*Участник на протяжении ...*

- [2 месяцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213000/user213000?tab=profile) (родительный)
- [5 месяцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206002/1pauletto?tab=profile) (родительный или именительный)
- [1 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189002/stas?tab=profile) (родительный)
- [1 год, 1 месяц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185980/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE?tab=profile) (именительный)
- [1 лет, 2 месяца](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183980/roman?tab=profile) (годы вообще неправильные, месяцы - именительный)
- [1 год, 5 месяцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32977/darth?tab=profile) (именительный)
- [3 лет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13968/soledar10?tab=profile) (родительный)
- [3 года, 1 месяцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13336/venzell?tab=profile) (годы - именительный, месяцы вообще неправильные)
- [3 года, 2 месяца](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/12995/andreyqin?tab=profile) (именительный)
- [3 года, 5 месяцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11816/progzdeveloper?tab=profile) (именительный)

Comment: Ссылки на профили, конечно, информативно, но они устареют не позднее, чем через месяц.

Comment: @alexolut Да, я понимаю, но надеюсь за месяц кто-нибудь что-нибудь сделает. Ну и новые ссылки можно будет получить, увеличив ID.

Comment: Учитывая, что по упомянутому Вами вопросу до сих пор нет решения (хотя и отмечено как `статус-завершено`), и даже отклика модераторов про этот статус, я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что за месяц что-то изменится.